# Estimating actual score from small sample when population known

Tags: sample-size, mean, population

My inclination here is that there's no statistically sounds way of doing this, but I want to verify this.

Suppose you have a population P, and you are measuring test scores across the population such that it's normally distributed and the average score is 50%.  However the population can be decomposed into a large set of Subpopulations of varying sizes.

Now, you want to give a ranking (percentile or ordinal) to these Subpopulations.  The problem is that subpopulations with a large N are more likely to have scores near the middle, whereas populations with a small N are more likely to fall on the edges of the bell curve.
Is there a way to 'adjust' the scores for the small groups such that they are better able to be compared to the large groups?

Comment: One thought I had is to assume the subpopulation is reflective of the general population as a prior.  Then adjust the distribution by treating the subpopulations scores as the posterior.

Comment: Can you say more about your situation & your data? Can you make this more concrete? Note that the standard error of the mean is a function of n such that as n increases, sample means will be closer to true means (cf the small schools mistake [pdf](http://faculty.cord.edu/andersod/MostDangerousEquation.pdf)).

Comment: There are 100000 students.  Each student has a score.  There are 10000 classess with sizes ranging from 1 student to 100 students and averaging 30.

The classes with 100 students tend to be closer to the mean, the classes with a few students are more likely to fall as outliers.

If you are trying to create an accurate ranking of all the classes - can you adjust for class size, such that the smaller classes aren't arbitrarily placed in the highest and lowest position just because of noise.

Comment: Are you trying to rank students or schools? Are the scores bounded (eg, by 0 to 100)? Do you have other attributes you want to adjust for besides school size (eg, parents' education)?

Comment: "Do you have other attributes you want to adjust for besides school size" - no, and I'm not so much trying to adjust as trying to normalize.

"Are you trying to rank students or schools?" - Schools

"Are the scores bounded (eg, by 0 to 100)" - Yes